# Redshift doesn't work under gnome

Tags: gnome, 15.04, redshift

I have some problems to get redshift working under Gnome. In Unity there is a taskbar-icon I can use to switch it off and on. Unfortunately there is none under Gnome. Whenever I start the redshift app it sends my monitor in night-state. How can I solve this? Can someone help me with the issue?

Answer (score 1):

From my quick and incomplete search to solve this problem myself and wild inferences from your post, you are attempting to download the package from the package repository that may only have panel support for unity. To use it without panel support, you may need to manually create and edit the program's config files documented in the link [here](http://jonls.dk/redshift/). I would suggest trying the shell extension found [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/685/redshift/) if you were using Gnome Shell 3.12, but I think 15.04 uses Gnome shell 3.14, based on the fact that I am on a freshly installed Ubuntu Gnome 15.04.

Good luck and have fun, we are on linux so tinker my friend.

Comment: Hi Buddhalobes, welcome to askubuntu! This might be a valid answer. One point of critique though. If a link is integral to the content of a post, you should summarize at least the main ideas/steps briefly. A link can always die.

Comment: Thanks for the note. While not new to Ubuntu I am new to attempting to be useful to the community, I'll keep this advice in mind for future posts..